Pluralization issue returns in editor stats on suggested edits ("1 edit suggestions")
The "reviewer stats" on suggested edits no longer properly show in singular form when there is only one edit suggestion approved, reviewed, improved, or cancelled.

This was fixed before, but has since regressed.

The pluralization issue has fixed. It works for me.
See an example:


Pang had 28 edit suggestions approved, 0 edit suggestions rejected, and 1 edit suggestion canceled.

And see my example:


user1176409 has 1 edit suggestion approved, 5 edit suggestions rejected, and 4 edit suggestions improved.


Nice, but shouldn't "has" be "has had"? The present tense there sounds as if the actions are not actually completed and are still in some kind of queue.

So, not "Community has 2781 edit suggestions approved...," but "Community has had 2781 edit suggestions approved..."

@QuackE.Duck I don’t think that’s a bug, as it didn’t change from the past. Maybe you can ask a new question about the grammar in the suggested edit review queue?

I wouldn't start a whole new question over something that minor, but it would be nice if they change it sometime in the future, if that screen gets edited again for any reason :)

Cf. my unanswered question

@J.W.Tanner I hadn't even noticed that, and had assumed the stats were meant to refer to edits the 'reviewer' had suggested themselves (and their outcomes)! If that isn't the case and the stats are supposed to be the reviewer's actions on other people's suggested edits, then you're right that there's a much bigger problem than just the tense being used!
